# autostretch uitextview, scrollview and static cells

Tags: xcode, uitextview

I have a uitableview with four static cells
First cell has a uitextview
second and third and regular cells
Fourth cell has uitextview

I need first and fourth cell to grow and shrink based on the content size. Fourth cell is going to have much larger text, so whole page should scroll for that.

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks.

D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    // Your code to find height of the text whic will display in UITextView.

}else{

    // your default cell height
}
```

}

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!